# How to get approval for my app to receive pages_messaging approval?

Tags: facebook, chatbot, review

I have a chat bot linked from Dialogflow to Facebook Messenger. Everything is set up but now it just needs pages_messaging permission approval from the Facebook team. I have submitted the request and the Facebook team messaged me this:
*This is a test message from the Facebook team. Please respond from your app within 2 days to confirm that the integration is functioning.*

However, the Facebook team test account is not able to receive messages from my app due to the app not having the pages_messaging permission in the first place. What should I do now? Will they not accept my request? Please help, I am new to this. Thanks!